# Approximating the constant term of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $P(T)$ be a polynomial in $T\in \mathbb R^n$ such that when $T$ is large, there is a function $F(T)$ such that $$|F(T)-P(T)|\leq Ke^{-\epsilon||T||}$$ where $K$ is a constant independent of $T$ and $\epsilon>0$.

Suppose I want to find the constant term, $P(0)$. Does is makes sense to do so by finding an expression for $F(T)$ when $T$ is large, then evaluating that expression at $T=0$?

Comment: This inequality holds *only* for large $||T||$. Even if it's true for all $T$, $|F(0)-P(0)|\le K$, and it's useless

Comment: Right, clearly this is wrong. It turns out the proof I was trying to follow was much more intricate!